# How to force Encryption with valid certificate for SQL server connections?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssl-certificate, database-connection

I configured ForceEncryption to yes and selected the certificate on SQL server. 
 It's still allowing the connections from clients that are not passing the valid certificate and clients that are not using encryption.
 What's the point of ForcingEncryption on server if client side configuration can manipulate it ? 
How do I configure the SQL server to reject those clients ?

Answer (score -1):

There are too many unknowns here, starting with SQL Server version, the kind of certificate used, the operating system version, TLS version settings in the registry etc. etc.

Please be sure to read the following thoroughly. The feature does work. Just follow the docs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/enable-encrypted-connections-to-the-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: SQL server's version is 2016. Certificate is generated using AD and installed in SQL server. Sql server OS is windows server 2016. Client OS is Windows 10. Some Clients are using Windows 7. Same certificate is installed in some client's machine and it work fine. In some client's machine, certificate is not installed and it's still working fine. I've followed exact same link that you've provided. Here's the another post which is related to same problem: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52246/ms-sql-server-accepts-non-ssl-connections-even-with-force-encryption-enabled-on/144173

Comment: `clients that are not passing the valid certificate` so you want also to validate clients' certificates? That's a whole different story than the connection encryption itself. The connection can be encrypted even when a client doesn't have a certificate. Maybe this will be helpful https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3408/how-to-troubleshoot-ssl-encryption-issues-in-sql-server/

Comment: If the connection is encrypted with unsafe certificate, it can be easily decrypted. So I want to allow only valid certificates. That's clear in the question. And the link that you've suggested is not having any info about this issue.

Comment: "If the connection is encrypted with unsafe certificate, it can be easily decrypted." If you are able to successfully prove that to a cryptologist, you're going to be famous and rich. I assume you meant that with untrusted certificate or with no certificate at all any client can connect to this SQL Server and you want to prevent that, you want only selected, trusted clients to be able to use the database. But then the issue is far more sophisticated than my donated time allows.